# Any m3u8 playlist example to use EXT-X-MAP tag

Tags: ios, html5-video, http-live-streaming

the tag is introduced in draft-09 of the HLS spec, without any examples.

```
   3.4.13.  EXT-X-MAP   

   The EXT-X-MAP tag specifies how to obtain the Transport Stream PAT/  
   PMT for the applicable media segment.  It applies to every media 
   segment that appears after it in the Playlist until the next EXT-X-  
   DISCONTINUITY tag, or until the end of the playlist. 

   The EXT-X-MAP tag MUST NOT appear unless the Playlist also contains  
   the EXT-X-I-FRAMES-ONLY tag.  It is RECOMMENDED that the EXT-X-MAP   
   tag only be used for segments whose resource does not start with a   
   PAT/PMT. 

   Its format is:   

   #EXT-X-MAP:<attribute-list>  

   The following attributes are defined:    

   URI  

   The value is a quoted-string containing a URI that identifies a  
   resource that contains the Transport Stream PAT/PMT.  This attribute 
   is mandatory.    

   BYTERANGE    

   The value is a quoted-string specifying a byte range into the    
   resource identified by the URI attribute.  This range SHOULD contain 
   only the Transport Stream PAT/PMT.  The format of the byte range is  
   described in Section 3.4.1.  This attribute is optional; if it is not    
   present, the byte range is the entire resource indicated by the URI. 

   The EXT-X-MAP tag appeared in version 5 of the protocol.
```

Answer (score 5):

Example for **PAT/PMT** initalization length `560` starting at offset `0` in `main.mp4`

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:5
#EXT-X-VERSION:7
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="./slow_loading.php?delay=5&resource=crypt0.key",IV=0xbf9840dc7d7fa163301a6c38844d6239
#EXT-X-MAP:URI="main.mp4",BYTERANGE="560@0"
#EXTINF:4.96907,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:25312@560
main.mp4
#EXTINF:4.96907,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:25440@25872
main.mp4
#EXTINF:4.96907,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:25440@51312
main.mp4
#EXTINF:4.96907,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:25440@76752
main.mp4
...
```

[Source](http://qtdevseed.apple.com/qadrift/testcases/tc-0912.php)

Comment: thanks for the IV in the example, better than textual description in section 5.2 of RFC8216